# Getting error looks like we got no XML document in soap apo

Tags: magento2

I am trying to use 3rd party soap API , but when I am calling API , I am getting error
"looks like we got no XML document"

My Code is as below

```
 $options = [
                'UserName' => 'xxxx',
                'Password' => 'xxxx',
                'Email'     => 'xx',
                 'Mobile' => 'xxxx'
            ];





$soapClient = $this->soapClientFactory->create(self::WSDL , ['trace' => $trace]);

       $soapClient->functionName($options));
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

This happens, for example, when your credentials are not correct.

For debugging, I'd recommend to wrap your code inside a `try...catch` block like this:

```
try {
    $soapResponse = $soapClient->functionName($options));
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
    echo $e->getTraceAsString()."\n\n";

    echo "Last Response:\n";
    var_dump($soapClient->__getLastResponse());
    die("\n");
}
```